# Vaadin: v-leaflet-editable: PolygonField: redrawing Polygons

Tags: leaflet, polygon, vaadin8

I tried different versions of **v-leaflet-editable** (Vaadin). I am using PolygonField. I can draw a polygon okay but when I try to redraw the polygon I get an error. With each Version of v-leaflet-editable I get a different error.

> code

```
  Component vaadinComponent = new CssLayout(new PolygonField());
      vaadinComponent.setSizeFull();
      return vaadinComponent;
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the versions of v-leaflet-editable and v-leaflet. Use this combination and you should be fine:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>v-leaflet</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>v-leaflet-editable</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```